# Minimum Equal Pairs in Set Containing Specific Values

Tags: computer-science

I'm currently working on a program which involves presenting equal pairs of values to a user, from a list pseudo-randomly populated with **values between 1 and 8**.

E.g. [1,5,5,4,3,4,5,5] would return 3 pairs of equal values:
(5,5)
(4,4)
(5,5)

How would I calculate the minimum number of equal pairs in a list of length *n*?

Comment: The answer is $\max\left(0,\lceil0.5n\rceil-4\right)$

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the formula to me please?